# DistanceOp.nearestPoints wrong result?

Tags: distance, wgs84, jts-topology-suite

in order to compute distance in WGS84 geometries, I first call DistanceOp.nearestPoints(g1, g2) from JTS 1.13 to compute the nearest points of this geometries, where:

```
g1 = LINESTRING (14.796 47.9467, 14.7975 47.9476, 14.798 47.9479)

g2 = LINESTRING (14.7979 47.9463, 14.7983 47.947)
```

and get as result points:

```
14.797799534826732, 47.947763568684266

14.798254700000001, 47.94696810000001
```

**These are not the nearest points of that two geometries.**

Nearest points would be (computed with JTS test builder):

POINT(14.79782352941177 47.947794117647064)

POINT(14.7983 47.947)
I have a unit test to illustrate the problem:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    WKTReader2 wkt = new WKTReader2(GF.get());
    try {
        this.moehrStr = wkt
                .read("LINESTRING (14.7959896 47.9466932, 14.7974574 47.9475678, 14.7979962 47.9478761)");
        this.laatzerStr = wkt.read("LINESTRING (14.797857 47.9462533, 14.7982547 47.9469681)");
        this.moehrNode = wkt.read("POINT (14.7974574 47.9475678)");
        this.LaatzNode = wkt.read("POINT (14.7982547 47.9469681)");

        System.out.println(OsmDistanceComputer.getDistanceInMeter(this.moehrStr, this.laatzerStr));
        System.out.println(this.moehrStr.contains(this.moehrNode));
        System.out.println(this.laatzerStr.touches(this.LaatzNode));
        System.out.println(OsmDistanceComputer.getDistanceInMeter(this.moehrNode, this.LaatzNode));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

GF is a 4326 SRID with 100000d precision. OsmDistanceComputer is :

public class OsmDistanceComputer {

```
public static Double getDistanceInMeter(Geometry g1, Geometry g2) {
    try {
        Coordinate[] c = DistanceOp.nearestPoints(g1, g2);

        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
        GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
        gc.setStartingPosition(JTS.toDirectPosition(c[0], crs));
        gc.setDestinationPosition(JTS.toDirectPosition(c[1], crs));
        // Double dist = JTS.orthodromicDistance(c[0], c[1],
        // DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        double dist = gc.getOrthodromicDistance();

        return dist;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

As result i get:

> 94.43004352415576
>
> true
>
> true
>
> 89.06942899300353

I compute distance between linestrings and than between points which are part of the linestrings. What does not make sense is why the distance of the linestrings is greater than that of the points which are contained in the linestrings.

Comment: I believe that you should show more about your code.

Comment: i finally got to this problem again and updated the description with a unit test

Answer (score 1):

Did you check for typos? If I use your geometries I get your expected result:

```
LineString g1 = factory.createLineString(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(14.796, 47.9467), new Coordinate(14.7975, 47.9476), new Coordinate(14.798, 47.9479)});
LineString g2 = factory.createLineString(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(14.7979, 47.9463), new Coordinate(14.7983, 47.947)});

Coordinate[] coords = DistanceOp.nearestPoints(g1, g2);
```

Coordinates in `coords` are:

```
(14.79782352941177, 47.947794117647064, NaN)
(14.7983, 47.947, NaN)
```

Comment: thanks, i didnt get to the problem yet, I think its a bug in my software. Maybe later i try to make a unit test for it.

Comment: Did it work? Please accept the answer if it helped...

Comment: didn't, but thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in other part of the software, sorry for bothering ...